# Two autocompletes on a page, not adding selected item to correct place

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a page that has used a single autocomplete successfully for a long time. I am trying to add a second autocomplete, but the first and the second autocomplete add the item to the same table; what am I doing wrong? If I switch the order of the two autocompletes it will always add the items selected from either autocompletes into the same table.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#assistantInstructorAutoCompleteList").tablesorter({
      widthFixed: true,
      widgets: ["zebra"],
      headers: {
        1: {
          sorter: false
        }
      }
    });
    $("#orgallowedAutoCompleteList").tablesorter({
      widthFixed: true,
      widgets: ["zebra"],
      headers: {
        1: {
          sorter: false
        }
      }
    });

    $("#assistantInstructor").autoCompleteList({
      source: "/training/load/course_ins_ALL_lookup.asp",
      appendTo: "#assistantInstructors",
      //      itemName: "assistantInstructors",
      headers: [{
        name: "Assistant or Trainee Instructors",
        size: 90
      }, {
        name: ""
      }, ],
      noResultsMessage: "No Results Found. Users registered for this course cannot be added as instructors."
    });

    $("#orgallowed").autoCompleteList({
      source: "/training/load/OrgLookup.asp",
      appendTo: "#allowedOrganizations",
      //         itemName: "allowedOrganizations",
      headers: [{
        name: "Organizations Allowed To Register",
        size: 90
      }, {
        name: ""
      }, ],
      noResultsMessage: "No Results Found. "
    });

  });
</script>

<div id="orgsallowedSection">
  <hr class="grid_12" style="width: 950px;" />
  <h6 class="grid_12">Organizations Allowed to Register</h6>
  <div class="grid_12">
    <input tabindex="15" type="text" id="orgallowed" name="orgallowed" value="" style="width: 400px;" class="" placeholder="Begin typing in organization name to select">


    <table id="orgallowedAutoCompleteList" class="tablesorter">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 90%">Organizations Allowed To Register</th>
          <th style="width: 10%;">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <% Do While NOT RSAOrgs.EOF  %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input id="allowedOrganizations" name="allowedOrganizations" value="<%= RSAOrgs(" org_id ")%>" type="hidden">
              <%= RSAOrgs("org_nm") %>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
              <a href="remove_allowed_org.asp?coid=<%=courseOfferingId%>&oid=<%=RSAOrgs(" org_id ")%>&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=110&width=450" class="thickbox" title="Remove Allowed Organization">
                <img src="/images/close.gif"></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <%  RSAOrgs.MoveNext
                Loop    
            %>
      </tbody>
    </table>


    <div id="instructionSection">
      <hr class="grid_12" style="width: 950px;" />
      <div class="grid_2" style="width: 70px;">
        <h6>Instructors</h6>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_12" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <input tabindex="16" type="text" id="assistantInstructor" name="assistantInstructor" value="" style="width: 400px;" class="" placeholder="Begin typing assistant or trainee instructor’s name to select" />

        <table id="assistantInstructorAutoCompleteList" class="tablesorter">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 90%">Assistant or Trainee Instructors</th>
              <th style="width: 10%;">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <%Do While (Not AIR.EOF) %>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input id="assistantInstructors" name="assistantInstructors" value="<%= AIR(" user_id ")%>" type="hidden">
                  <% Response.write AIR("last_nm") & ", " & AIR("first_nm") %>
                </td>
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, `.autoCompleteList()` is not a jQuery UI widget.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  So come to find out, .autocompleteList was/is a custom JS function that I was not aware of from a previous programmer for this site. It was not until Twisty's comment (Thank You) that got me digging further. Prior, I was just assuming it was a function of JQuery UI autocomplete and could not get a second one to work on the same page. The custom .autocompleteList function adds the selected value to a table row for a one-to-many relation. Tweaked it a bit to work twice (two autocomplete dropdowns) on a single page.  Issue Resolved

For those interested, here is the custom js:

(function ($) {
var settings;

```
$.fn.autoCompleteList = function (options) {
    var noResultsLabel = 'No Results Found'
    settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.autoCompleteList.defaults, options);

    this.each(function () {
        if ($("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "AutoCompleteList").length) {
            $tableToMod = $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "AutoCompleteList")
        }
        else {
            $tableToMod = $('<table id="' + $(this).attr("id") + 'AutoCompleteList" class="tablesorter"><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>')
            $tableHeadRow = $("<tr></tr>");
            $tableToMod.children('thead').append($tableHeadRow);
            $.each(settings.headers, function (index, item) {
                var headerSize = (item.size != undefined && item.size.toString().length) ? item.size.toString().replace(/\D/g, '') : ((100 / settings.headers.length));
                if (item.name != '') {
                    $tableHeadRow.append('<th  style="width:' + headerSize + '%"><span class="smalltext">' + item.name + '</span><span style="float: right;"><img src="/training/images/whiteSortArrows.png"></th>');
                }
                else {
                    $tableHeadRow.append('<th style="width:' + headerSize + '%">&nbsp;</th>');
                }
            });
        }

        

        var setWidth = (settings.listWidth == 0) ? $(this).css("width"):settings.listWidth;
        $tableToMod.css("width", setWidth);

        $(this).after($tableToMod);
       
        $tableToMod.on("click", "#removeField", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            $tableToMod.trigger("update");
            var sorting = [[0, 0]];
            $tableToMod.trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
            settings.onAfterRemove.call(this, $tableToMod);
        });

        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: settings.source,
            response: function (event, ui) {
                if (!ui.content == null && !ui.content.length) {
                    var result = { label: noResultsLabel, id: '' };
                    ui.content.push(result);
                }
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).val('');
                if (ui.item.label != noResultsLabel && ui.item.id != '') {
                    $.fn.autoCompleteList.AddToList(settings.itemName, ui.item);
                }
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (ui.item.label != noResultsLabel && ui.item.id != '') {
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                }
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined || !$.trim(ui.item.id)) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            }

        });
    });
};

$.fn.autoCompleteList.defaults = {
    source: "",
    itemName: "listItem",
    listWidth: 0,
    fields: {},
    headers: [],
    onAfterAdd: function () { },
    onAfterRemove: function () { }
};

$.fn.autoCompleteList.AddToList = function (name, item) {
    $tableRow = $("<tr></tr>");
    $tableToMod
        .children('tbody:last')
        .append($tableRow);
    $tableRow.append("<td><input name=\"" + name + "\" value=\"" + item.id + "\" type=\"hidden\">" + item.label + "</td>");
    $.each(settings.fields, function (index, value) {
        $tableRow.append("<td>" + item[value] + "</td>");
    });

    $tableRow.append("<td style=\"text-align:center;\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"removeField\"><img  src=\"/images/close.gif\" alt=\"delete\"></a></td>");
    $tableToMod.trigger("update");
    var sorting = [[0, 0]];
    $tableToMod.trigger("sorton", [sorting]);

    settings.onAfterAdd.call(this, $tableToMod, $tableRow);
};

$.fn.autoCompleteList.Clear = function () {
    $tableToMod.children('tbody').empty();
};
```

})(jQuery);